# Conditional breakpoint dependent on caller enabling/disabling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a method that's called from many, many places.

```
void foo()
{
    do_some_work();
}
```

The setup for a debugging session is a pain.  If I'm debugging this:

```
void main()
{
    func1();   // which deep, deep down calls foo() over and over and over
    func2();   // which calls foo() over and over and over

    foo();     // This is the one that I actually want to debug
}
```

I want to debug `foo()` but only from that last call.  There are no convenient global, public, static variables I can use to set a breakpoint conditional on that I know of.

What I'd *really* like to do is something like this:

```
void main()
{
    func1();   // which deep, deep down calls foo() over and over and over
    func2();   // which calls foo() over and over and over

    Enable_debugger();
    foo();     // This is the one that I actually want to debug
}
```

Set my breakpoint in `foo()` and have it skipped for every instance except the last one.

Is there an approach I can take?

Why not just set the debug point in `main()` and then step-in?  Because to step down into `foo()` is a *lot* of step-ins.

**Edit**
I did find a slight cheat.  I can do this:

```
  System.Threading.Thread.SetData(
          System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("BREAKPOINT"), "on");
```

And then set the conditional breakpoint on:

```
 (string)System.Threading.Thread.GetData(
          System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("BREAKPOINT")) == "on"
```

Comment: _There are no convenient global, public, static variables I can use to set a breakpoint conditional on that I know of._
Is there any reason why you can't add one? You could add a global variable that you set to `true` just before `foo()` in main, and set a conditional breakpoint inside `foo()`?

Comment: Depending on your VS version you can right click on a breakpoint and set "conditions".  One of those conditions is a hit count.  So if you can determine an exact count or a minimum threshold you can set accordingly.  Also, Hi Clinton haha

Comment: @Clinton Pierce, It seems that you have found the solution in your side, if possible, you could share the solution as the answer(not in the issue/comment). So you could mark and close this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a global variable, say, `debugFoo`, which is initiated to `false` and set to `true` just before your call to `foo()` in `main()`.

```
public static void foo()
{   // <-- Conditional breakpoint here.
    Console.WriteLine(debugFoo);
}

public static bool debugFoo = false;

public static void Main()
{
    foo();
    debugFoo = true;
    foo();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then set a conditional breakpoint inside `foo()`, with the condition being,

```
debugFoo == true
```

So depending on when you turn `debugFoo` on and off you can hit that breakpoint.

---

**EDIT**

If two are not visible to each other, a secondary approach I'd consider is modifying parameters of `foo()` if that's a possibility.

```
public static void foo(bool doDebug = false)
{   // <-- Conditional breakpoint here
    Console.WriteLine(doDebug);
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("No debug");
    foo();
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
    foo(true);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And set a conditional breakpoint:

```
doDebug == true
```

This way you don't have to modify other existing calls to `foo()`, but pass `true` to the single call in `main()` that you want to debug.

Comment: This works only if the two assemblies are visible to each other.  I've ruled out a "global variable" for just this reason.  There aren't any in-process.

Comment: Is modifying the parameters of `foo()` an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a compatible version of Visual Studio you can set [Conditional Breakpoints](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition/). I don't have a list of versions that work, however the easiest way to follow the steps and see if the menu option is there for you.

1. Go into your `foo()` method and set a breakpoint at the first line
2. Right click the breakpoint and click "Conditions"
3. From there you can set a condition based on "Hit Counter":

[image: Conditional Breakpoint in Visual Studio]

If you can find the exact count of `foo()` calls you wanna skip (or even a minimum threshold) this *should* be a way to solve your issue.

With this approach you wont need to write any code and you can solve this *solely* using the IDE.

Comment: Decent idea.  Getting the hit count the first time might be a pain though.... but so far plausible.